# Declare a constraint that holds for Vinyl records having a specific field

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, vinyl

I use [vinyl](https://github.com/VinylRecords/Vinyl/) to declare a number of different record types, some of which have a field called `Content` with a specific type `LanguageContent`. For the functions that depend on the field being present in the record, I want to have a type like:

```
getContent :: HasContent a => a -> LanguageContent
getContent a = a ^. rlens SContent . unAttr
```

(Function given for illustration only; there are many functions taking something that `HasContent` and doing different things with it.)

Now I just need to declare `HasContent` as a constraint. The closest I can get using `Data.Vinyl.Notation` is:

```
getContent :: (Content ∈ fs) => Rec Attr fs -> LanguageContent
```

A type family can be declared but the function does not typecheck:

```
type family HasContent c :: Constraint
type instance HasContent (Rec Attr rs) = Content ∈ rs

getContent :: HasContent a => a -> LanguageContent
getContent a = a ^. rlens SContent . unAttr

Could not deduce (a ~ Rec Attr rs0)
from the context (HasContent a)
```

I can make a constraint with two parameters which works but isn't ideal (`rs` is a parameter that I have to repeat everywhere):

```
type HasContent c rs = (c ~ Rec Attr rs, Content ∈ rs)
```

Without the extra parameter (see answer by @ChristianConkle), I just get:

```
type HasContent c = (c ~ Rec Attr rs, Content ∈ rs)

Not in scope: type variable ‘rs’
```

How do I declare a constraint which only holds for such `Rec Attr fs` that `Content ∈ fs`?

Comment: What is wrong with the inferred type - which is precisely `Content ∈ fs => Rec Attr fs -> LanguageContent`? This type is much more descriptive than `HasContent a => a -> LanguageContent`. If you really want the latter, define a class `class HasContent a where getContent :: a -> LanguageContent` and an instance `instance (Content ∈ rs) => HasContent (Rec Attr rs) where ...`. If you plan to have other instances, this approach has merit, but if this is the only instance, just use the function as-is.

Comment: There are quite a few functions which all have the same constraint, and I don't want to repeat it everywhere.

Comment: It's not strictly proper to integrate answers into the question. If you want to include bits from the answers @user2407038 and I provided, please explain what you're doing in the answer so that the conversation doesn't become confusing.

Comment: Also, referring to `rs` in the type `(c ~ Rec Attr rs, Content ∈ rs)` as a "phantom parameter" is unhelpful. In fully monomorphic code, `rs` will be specialized to a specific, concrete, meaningful value representing the fields or rows of the record.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit*: [@Koterpillar's test file](https://github.com/koterpillar/vinyl-test/blob/851f03efbb4dea1b95d81a94c84eb92ff342413d/Main.hs#L57) seems to demonstrate that this type synonym doesn't work the way I expected; it appears the constraint is not available inside the definition. It'd be worth investigation or a follow-up question to determine why. It had been my understanding that `(C x => T x) -> Y` was equivalent to `C x => T x -> Y`, but the fact that the example doesn't work seems to belie that. */Edit*

I think you want to write this instead:

```
type RecWithContent rs = Content ∈ rs => Rec Attrs rs

getContent' :: RecWithContent rs -> LanguageContent
```

This is really just wrapping up the constraint in a type synonym. You need `RankNTypes` and probably a bunch of other extensions.

Your existing attempts to solve the problem and leave just `a` on the right hand side of the `=>` boil down to this type synonym:

```
type HasContent c = (Content ∈ fs, c ~ Rec Attr fs)
```

In other words, you want `HasContent` to witness two separate things: that `Content` is in `fs`, and that the type parameter `c` is equal to `Rec Attr fs`.

I don't think you can do this in a way that's convenient for you. With the type synonym, the surface-level problem is that `rs` is not in scope on the right hand side. The deeper issue is that you're asking the compiler to make up `fs`; you want to write something like `exists fs. (Content ∈ fs, c ~ Rec Attr fs)`, which is not expressible directly in current Haskell.

Your type family solution won't help, but for a different reason. In the definition of `getContent`, the compiler needs proof that `a` really is `Rec Attr rs0` in order to use `rlens` (or probably `unAttr`), but it can't deduce that from the type family. (You know that there's only one type instance, but the compiler doesn't use that logic.)

Comment: What are `b` and `a` in the definitions of `RecWithContent`? With or without them, I get this: http://lpaste.net/121586

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the type variables; I shouldn't have included `b` or `a`; I've edited the answer. The definition in your lpaste, `type HasContent = (Content ∈ rs) => Rec Attr fs`, won't work because the `rs` is hidden on the right-hand side of the type synonym; it needs to be exposed in the signature of the overall function to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: To fix the first error, fix the typo in the definition of `HasContent`. There's only one type variable. The second error might be something else; your `unAttr` may be too polymorphic to fix `fs0` and `i0`. Does your original `getContent :: Content ∈ fs => Rec Attr fs -> LanguageContent` typecheck? The signatures should be equivalent, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: http://lpaste.net/123101. `getContent` with the constraint specified manually typechecks, as well as the two-parameter typeclass (`HasContent a rs`, as in the question).

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in [123101](http://lpaste.net/123101) and your comment to explain the error. Please include a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, then; it looks like my "best" solution doesn't work. There must be something I'm misunderstanding about the way GHC deals with nested constraints. (It's not a well-specified corner of the language.) You could ask a follow-up question if you're interested in that approach.